# How to use tags in hooks on cucumberjs with webdriverio?

Tags: cucumber, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I want to have a new clean session after each of my tests.
In order to do that I use reloadSession() in an afterScenario hook

```
 afterScenario: ({tags: 'not @last'}, async function (world,result) {
        await browser.reloadSession();
    })
```

However, I don't want this hook triggered on the last scenario (I don't want an extra session to reload if it's not needed) so I tagged my last test on the feature file as @last.

```
  @last
  Scenario: An anonymous user cannot login with the wrong credentials
    Given I am on the 'login' page
    When I login with invalid credentials
      | username  | password      |
      | wrongUser | wrongPassword |
    Then I should the following error message
      | error                                        |
      | Error: Incorrect login or password provided. |
```

When I try to do this and run the hook for all the tests without the @last tag, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This we can handle in 2 ways:

1. Use ~ instead of not like (May or May not work):

   afterScenario: ({tags: '~@last'}, async function (world,result) {
   await browser.reloadSession();
   });
2. Take 'scenario' as parameter to this async function like this:

   afterScenario: (async function (world,result, scenario) {
   let isLastTag;
   scenario.pickle.tags.forEach(tag => {
   isLastTag = tag.equals("@last");
   });

   ```
            if (!isLastTag)
            await browser.reloadSession();
   ```

   });

While executing, cucumberjs stores complete scenario info in 'scenario' and using that, we can filter out like above

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I needed

Comment: I want to run a hook for a particular tag :
For ex: `beforeScenario:({tags: '@ssoScenario'},  function (scenario) {` But this hook is run for all scenarios and not just @ssoScenario. 

Can someone help me how to run a hook for a particular tag ?

Comment: Which scripting language are you using? @user3378508. You can use async and await to see accurate results